# Shiro gets different sessions for every getSession()

Tags: java, session, shiro

I want to do the session attributes validation recently.I made an interceptor that when requests come it will get the shiro session to set some attributes in the session.But I found that I always got the different shiro sessions when use the `getSession()` for the same user who has logged in the system.

> Here is the shiro configuration xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

```
<description>Shiro Configuration</description>

<bean id="sessionIdGenerator" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.JavaUuidSessionIdGenerator"/>

<bean id="sessionDAO" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO">
    <property name="activeSessionsCacheName" value="shiro-activeSessionCache"/>
    <property name="sessionIdGenerator" ref="sessionIdGenerator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionManager" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager">
    <property name="globalSessionTimeout" value="3600000"/>
    <property name="deleteInvalidSessions" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionValidationSchedulerEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionValidationScheduler" ref="sessionValidationScheduler"/>
    <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO"/>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="sessionValidationScheduler" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.quartz.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler ">
    <property name="interval" value="60000"/>
    <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
</bean>-->

<bean id="sessionValidationScheduler" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
    <property name="interval" value="3600000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="shiroDbRealm"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="shiroDbRealm" class="com.aspire.cms.service.impl.ShiroDbRealm">
</bean>

<bean id="systemLogoutFilter" class="com.aspire.cms.filter.SystemLogoutFilter"></bean>

<!-- Shiro Filter -->
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/main"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="filters">
        <map>
            <entry key="logout" value-ref="systemLogoutFilter" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /login = authc
            /ajaxLogin = anon
            /logout = logout
            /static/** = anon
            /** = user
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
      depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager"/>
    <property name="arguments" ref="securityManager"/>
</bean>
```

> Here is the code to get shiro session

```
public class CsrfInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CsrfInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession();
    System.out.println("==========sessionId:"+session.getId());
    String sessionCsrfToken = (String) session.getAttribute(CsrfTokenManager.CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_ATTR_NAME);

    if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        String CsrfToken = CsrfTokenManager.getTokenFromRequest(request);
        if (CsrfToken == null || !CsrfToken.equals(sessionCsrfToken)) {
            String reLoginUrl = "/login?backurl="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(getCurrentUrl(request), "utf-8");

           response.sendRedirect(reLoginUrl);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried : `Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession(false);`

Comment: Different session during the same request? or multiple requests?

Comment: @Xin Meng Yes,I tried.But it didn't work.

Comment: @Brian request During multiple requests,But when I delete the definitions of  `sessionIdGenerator` `sessionValidationScheduler` `sessionDAO` `securityManager` etc,I got the same session.Don't know why.